# Assign a random value - either 0 or 1 - to factors of a list

Tags: r, simulate

I have a list with 1000 factors, each ranging from 1 to 1000 and each factor appears 15 times. I want to either assign 0 or 1 to every factor that has the same value. For instance, factor 1 that appears 15 times has to have always the value 0. Any idea on how to do this? Basically, I would like to have two columns, one with the factors, and one with the value (0 or 1) that each factor has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
my_binary <- as.numeric(my_factor) %% 2
```

So, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(number = 1:20, factor = rep(letters[1:5], 4))
df$binary <- as.numeric(df$factor) %% 2
```

Gives you

```
df
#>    number factor binary
#> 1       1      a      1
#> 2       2      b      0
#> 3       3      c      1
#> 4       4      d      0
#> 5       5      e      1
#> 6       6      a      1
#> 7       7      b      0
#> 8       8      c      1
#> 9       9      d      0
#> 10     10      e      1
#> 11     11      a      1
#> 12     12      b      0
#> 13     13      c      1
#> 14     14      d      0
#> 15     15      e      1
#> 16     16      a      1
#> 17     17      b      0
#> 18     18      c      1
#> 19     19      d      0
#> 20     20      e      1
```

---

And if you want arbitrary numbers at a specified probability you would do:

```
numbers <- c(0, 1)
probs <- c(0.75, 0.25)
df <- data.frame(number = 1:20, factor = rep(letters[1:5], 4))
df$binary <- sample(numbers, length(levels(df$factor)), prob = probs, T)[as.numeric(df$factor)]
```

Comment: this works, but I was wondering if it was possible for the binary column to depend on a probability. That is, with 0.25 probability is 1, with 0.75 probability is 0. How do I do that? Thanks in advance!